# Heatmap 3.0.7 version not working

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I am working with Highcharts version 3.0.7. My heatmap does not show up in that version, but it works in version 4.0.* .

See the code below ([and JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8yJjD/1/)):

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 40
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            title: null
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 320
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Sales per employee',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [[0,0,10],[0,1,19],[0,2,8],[0,3,24],[0,4,67],[1,0,92],[1,1,58],[1,2,78],[1,3,117],[1,4,48],[2,0,35],[2,1,15],[2,2,123],[2,3,64],[2,4,52],[3,0,72],[3,1,132],[3,2,114],[3,3,19],[3,4,16],[4,0,38],[4,1,5],[4,2,8],[4,3,117],[4,4,115],[5,0,88],[5,1,32],[5,2,12],[5,3,6],[5,4,120],[6,0,13],[6,1,44],[6,2,88],[6,3,98],[6,4,96],[7,0,31],[7,1,1],[7,2,82],[7,3,32],[7,4,30],[8,0,85],[8,1,97],[8,2,123],[8,3,64],[8,4,84],[9,0,47],[9,1,114],[9,2,31],[9,3,48],[9,4,91]],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'black',
                style: {
                    textShadow: 'none',
                    HcTextStroke: null
                }
            }
        }]

    });
});
```

Comment: What are the requirements? Must that Highcharts version be used? Can any Heatmap version be used?

Comment: -1 Probably because if you were to actually *check* the documentation, it explicitly says that they are available *since* `version 4` http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#plotOptions.heatmap

Comment: My bad, I could not figure that out in the API. But I did go through the API. More over I saw the Heatmap.js file in v3.0.7. Hence I thought the Heatmap is available in that version also. But in real, its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heatmap is available since `3.0.8.`

Look at the example: http://jsfiddle.net/8yJjD/3/